# Can't use RSYNC daemon via SSH connection

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have a problem while trying to use RSYNC with daemon and SSH connection.

What I wan't to do is simply login to rsync without pass and be able to use the rsync daemon.

Here is my conf file (/etc/rsyncd.conf):

```
uid = rsync
gid = rsync

[yxz]
    path = /home/pierre/xyz
    read only = false
    auth users = rsync
    hosts allow = <myIP>
```

/home/pierre/xyz has gid wich rsync user can reach.

This is working (but is not using the daemon):

```
rsync -rzP --stats --ignore-existing --remove-sent-files rsync@mydomain.fr:/home/pierre/xyz/ /media/xyz --include="*.cfg" --exclude="*"
```

This is not working (using the daemon), but rsync asks me for pass and then says "@ERROR: auth failed on module xyz" because I don't have configure authentification this way :

```
rsync -rzP --stats --ignore-existing --remove-sent-files rsync://rsync@mydomain.fr/xyz/ /media/xyz --include="*.cfg" --exclude="*"
```

This is not working (using the daemon):

```
rsync -rzP -e "ssh -l rsync" --stats --ignore-existing --remove-sent-files rsync://rsync@mydomain.fr/xyz/ /media/xyz --include="*.cfg" --exclude="*"
```

Here is the error message:

> rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
>   rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]

With -v option to the ssh command, it says connection is allowed, so I suppose rsync is the problem, not ssh.

Any idee ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

1. **Make sure that you stop and disable the `rsync` system service**.  E.g. if you are using `systemd`: `systemctl disable --now rsync`.
2. Remove `-l rsync` from the rsync command

   `rsync -rzP -e "ssh" --stats --ignore-existing --remove-sent-files rsync://mydomain.fr/xyz/ /media/xyz --include="*.cfg" --exclude="*"`
3. Remove `auth users = rsync` from `rsyncd.conf`
4. I found that if I was not using `root`, I had to also add `use chroot = no` in `rsyncd.conf`.

> Great it works, but what sort of authentification is made ?

The connection is authenticated as usual for the `ssh` command (specifically, the same as `ssh mydomain.fr`).

This does *not* involve the system service `rsync`.  Instead it uses SSH to start and communicate with an instance of `rsync --server --daemon .`.  You can see this command being started if you replace `-e "ssh"` with `-e "ssh -v"`.

The problem with using the system service `rsync` is that it does not encrypt the network connection, so the network is able to intercept and modify the data in transit.  This somewhat defeats the point of using any authentication.

---

Often this approach is used with a dedicated SSH key, using the `command=""` option in `authorized_keys` to restrict it to `rsync` only.  A side-benefit of doing so is that it overrides the command `rsync` tries to use, so you can force it to use `--config=~/rsyncd.conf` instead of creating a global `/etc/rsyncd.conf`.  IMO this is useful to avoid confusion IMO.  It is good practice because if you create the global config file, there is some risk that you will accidentally run the insecure system service.  For example Debian 9 enables the rsync system service by default, and will start it automatically at boot if you have created `/etc/rsyncd.conf`.

- https://gist.github.com/trendels/6582e95012f6c7fc6542
- https://indico.cern.ch/event/577279/contributions/2354037/attachments/1366772/2071442/Hepsysman-keeping-in-sync.pdf
- https://serverfault.com/questions/6367/cant-get-rsync-to-work-in-daemon-over-ssh-mode
- Unusual variant using a dedicated *user* with a custom shell, instead of `command=""` / `ForceCommand`, for some reason: http://mennucc1.debian.net/howto-ssh-rsyncd.html

Answer (score 1):

To use `rsync` daemon without a password, you should remove `auth users` line from your config file.

```
uid = rsync
gid = rsync

[yxz]
    path = /home/pierre/xyz
    read only = false
    hosts allow = <myIP>
```

After starting the daemon, you can refer the module either using `::` syntax or using `rsync://` prefix as follows

```
rsync -rzv rsync@mydomain.fr::xyz/ /media/xyz 

rsync -rzv rsync://rsync@mydomain.fr/xyz/ /media/xyz
```

More info: [man rsyncd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf)

Comment: Great it works, but what sort of authentification is made ?
Now, I can connect like this (note the "toto" user who doesn't exists on the distant system), which let me imagine there is no security:
rsync -rzP -e "ssh -l rsync" --stats --ignore-existing --remove-sent-files rsync://toto@mydomain.fr/xyz/ /media/xyz --include="*.cfg" --exclude="*"

Comment: Ya this is not secure. If you want to authenticate, you have to use `auth users` that specifies a comma and space-separated list of usernames that will be allowed to connect to this module and `secrets` specifies the name of a file that contains the username:password pairs used for authenticating this module. Refer man page for more info.

Comment: I know that :)
What I want to do is auth user with a key and not with a pass.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: then you can use rsync over ssh.

Comment: You're right, if I want to auth with a key, the solution is to do so through SSH, but in this case, it's not possible to use rsync daemon.
That the answer I was waiting for: it's not possible to rsync through SSH and use the daemon.